# Hardware RAID controller replacement/drawbacks

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

Apart from the price, is there any drawback to use hardware RAID controller to create a RAID 1 (mirror) array?

I mean, for example, is it possible to create the RAID 1 array with the baseboard RAID function (because of the cost) then later switch to a better PCI extension RAID controller? Or what if the PCI card became faulty? Can I replace it with one from the current market maybe from a different vendor? I'm not sure if those controllers write any metadata on the disks itself such as in case of SW RAID or keep that information in their own internal storage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I mean, for example, is it possible to create the RAID 1 array with the baseboard RAID function (because of the cost) then later switch to a better PCI extension RAID controller?

No, not without restoring from backup.

For many workloads, I would actually suggest going with software RAID today. CPU's are fast, and it means that you can easily mount drives in other, new systems if needed. There are drawbacks, such as lack of cache, so it's not ideal in I/O heavy environments, but in many cases it offers *good enough* performance - and the avoidance of HW reliance makes it appealing.

Comment: Thanks! I tought HW RAID is easier to create and manage a bootable array but I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: Recovery can be a bit trickier though. I think a long time ago some guy at a MSP made a meme video about this, they had a server that didn't restart correctly while it was running on the second disk. They sent emails to stop restarting the server until it could be serviced.

Comment: @GregAskew It can be a wash. Software RAID such as dmraid *can* be simpler if you suddenly have to bring it up again on different hardware. There's pro's and cons with both hardware and software RAID.

Comment: As long as it is documented it should be fine. I've seen everything from system that will start from a floppy disk to switching jumpers or cables.

Comment: *No, not without restoring from backup.* — piece of cake. Just use LVM on RAID (no matter which one, HW or SW) and you'll be able to move even from HW raid to SW raid or vice versa with very little downtime, as small as the time required to install the hardware and reboot. No backup needed (I mean, it's always needed, but in this case, you won't need to go through "restore from backup" path). BTW, I remember, you once asked "why LVM" — so this is why. It makes things quicker and easier to manage.

Answer (score 5):

Software RAIDs are superior to the hardware RAIDs these days. You get better performance and you have a point, you don’t get any vendor lock-in. We use MDRAID + XFS for our Veeam immutable backup repositories and plain ZoL setups as our primary file servers. No regrets!